# I have a College table and a Stream Table. College has one to many relationship with Stream table. Now if i delete a College it throws an error

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

In **Hibernate** I have 2 tables viz College and Stream, hence 2 POJO classes. Now College has many-to-many relation with Stream which is achieved by creating a `Set<Stream> streams = new HashSet<Stream>()` in the POJO class College. All the required mappings are done in the `College.hbm.xml` file.

Now, when I delete a College from the College table it throws an error: `update or delete on table "stream" violates foreign key constraint "fk1rk5ykysbvn2uddkm345fi00y" on table "college_stream".`

I have used `cascade="all"` in hibernate mapping file yet same error. What can I do??

```
  <id name="id" column="id"/>      
  <property name = "address" column="address"/>
  <property name = "country" column="country"/>
  <property name = "grants" column="grants"/>
  <property name = "name" column="name"/>
  <set name="streams" table="COLLEGE_STREAM" cascade="all">
        <key column="college_id" />
        <many-to-many column="stream_Id"  class="com.paramatrix.bean.Stream" />
  </set>
```

Comment: Do you have tables college, stream, and college_stream?  It looks like when you are deleting the college it tries to delete from a stream table, but there is a record that would get orphaned in college_stream.  it looks like it tries to delete the stream record before the college_stream.  Since there is a Foreign key relationship on the Stream that prevents the delete.

Comment: yes you got it right. So what will be the possible solution. I dont want to delete the streams at all, streams in Stream table will exist even if one or more colleges are deleted from College table. What I want to do is I just want to delete records from college_stream table which corresponds to the college that I deleted. If I delete a college with id=1 then the records with college with id=1 in college_stream table need to be deleted. Whereas stream table need to remain intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is going on here is that you have your Cascade All set on the Stream object.  So it is trying to delete the stream.  You need this set on the College object, and mapped by the CollegeStream.  I would try this

First Modify College and remove the `Set<Stream>` from it. Next create CollegeStream that extends College and maps them together:

```
public CollegeStream extends College {
    private College college;
    private Set<Stream> streams;
    // Getters/Setters
}
```

Then Map the CollegeStream to the College/Stream with Hibernate, adding the Cascade to the College mapping

```
<class name="CollegeStream" table="COLLEGE_STREAM">
    <many-to-one name="college" class="com.paramatrix.bean.College" cascade="all">
        <column name="college_id />
    </many-to-one>

    <set name="streams" table="STREAM">
        <key column="stream_id" />
        <many-to-many class="com.paramatrix.bean.Stream" />
    </set>
</class>
```

That way when you load your CollegeStream object it will contain the data from the college mapped with the set of streams.  When you delete the CollegeStream it should then delete the linked College as well as the CollegeStream without deleting the Stream.